# AWSEBCLI not reading env vars

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, circleci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to run AWSEBCLI inside a docker container. I am passing the access key and security token as env vars as described in the docs under ["Configuration Settings and Precedence"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html)

```
ERROR: CredentialsError - Operation Denied. You appear to have no credentials
```

Here is my docker file

```
FROM circleci/golang

ADD . /go/src

WORKDIR /go/src

RUN sudo apt-get -y -qq update --assume-yes
RUN sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential --assume-yes
RUN sudo pip install awscli=="1.16.9"
RUN sudo pip install awsebcli=="3.14.4"
RUN echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
RUN echo ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
CMD sudo eb deploy Circledocker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment defined in your user session and the **sudo** session are not the same.

```
RUN echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} -> Works
RUN sudo echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} -> Will not provide you the value.
```

Take a look at man sudo,  the **-E** flag :

```
-E, --preserve-env
         Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
         existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
         if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

So this normally works :

```
sudo -E bash -c 'echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
```

Try your `eb deploy` command like this :

```
sudo -E bash -c 'eb deploy Circledocker'
```

Hope it helps !